# ¿Como llamar Botones/Listas desde una clase a otra en JAVA?

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

Espero todo bien. He estado trabajando en un proyecto de clases, y tengo una duda que no he podido resolver (más bien estoy confundido). Tengo varios botones y listas desplegables que se repiten en varios paneles del programa; sin embargo, no quiero irlos programando en cada panel que haga. Quisiera saber como hacer para que esos botones y listas desplegables sean aceptados o puedan ser usados en otras clases/paneles.

```
    private void botonSalirPrograma() {

    //Boton de salir
    exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
    exitButton.setBounds(500, 520, 80, 30);
    exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    mainPanel.add(exitButton);
}
```

Adjunto el código de uno de los botones que se tiene que mostrar en cada panel.

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes tener una clase donde los instancies y que tenga getters que te devuelvan los componentes esos, así puedes añadirlos una y otra vez con solo llamar a un método. Luego si tengo un rato te añado un ejemplo si quieres :)

Comment: Hola @Benito-B! Te agradecería muchisimo si pudieras hacerlo, Saludos!

Comment: Ahí lo tienes. Cualquier duda ya sabes dónde estamos :) Suelo conectarme a SO todos los días y si tienes alguna duda o problemas con este ejemplo, en mi perfil está mi twitter también :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disculpa la tardanza, aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo usar una clase para *guardar* tus objetos y no tener que repetir código una y otra vez. Hay muchísimas mejoras que podrías hacer, y por supuesto muchas maneras de hacer esto, pero para ir empezando a ver cómo funcionan estas cosas seguro que te vale, y te ahorra problemas!
Primero, clase con el `main`, para probarlo esta ponla en un archivo diferente al siguiente, da igual cómo se llame, pero muy importante que tenga estos *imports*:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
```

Código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Primero creo una ventana y le pongo título, medidas, layout a null y DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Prueba");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setSize(600, 800);
    // También la centro, ya puestos
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    /*
     * El método que creé en nuestra "fábrica" de botones de salir requiere que se le pasen
     * las medidas y la posición del botón como un Rectangle, que es una de las opciones que
     * nos da Swing a la hora de setearle esas medidas/posición, así que empiezo creando uno
     */
    Rectangle position1 = new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 25);
    /*
     * Y luego añado el botón llamando directamente a la clase StaticWindowComponents
     * y el método correspondiente, pasándole el texto y el rectángulo
     */
    frame.getContentPane().add(StaticWindowComponents.getExitButton("Salir", position1));
    // Otra opción es crear el Rectangle directamente en la llamada al método, puesto que no lo volveré a usar
    frame.getContentPane().add(StaticWindowComponents.getExitButton("Salir también",
            new Rectangle(200, 225, 250, 100)));
    // Incluso podrías guardar el botón que devuelve el método y luego añadirlo como siempre!
    JButton button3 = StaticWindowComponents.getExitButton("Tercer botón",
            new Rectangle(25, 400, 125, 250));
    frame.getContentPane().add(button3);

    /*
     * Eso está muy bien si solo vamos a poner botones que siempre hagan lo mismo
     * pero con diferentes textos... Y si quiero que los botones hagan cosas diferentes?
     * Bueno, para eso podemos probar a crear un ActionListener aquí... y pasárselo
     * al segundo método de la clase StaticWindowComponents!
     * También podrías crear el new ActionListener directamente al llamar al método,
     * simplemente lo hago por separado para hacerlo más fácil de leer/seguir.
     */
    ActionListener salutationsListener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Salutations, human!");
        }
    };
    frame.getContentPane().add(StaticWindowComponents.getCustomButton("Saludar",
            new Rectangle(200, 25, 100, 100),
            salutationsListener));
    /*
     * Una manera más corta de escribir el actionListener es usar una lambda!
     * Con ellas se hace realmente fácil hacer botones customizados:
     */
    frame.getContentPane().add(StaticWindowComponents.getCustomButton("Byeee",
            new Rectangle(300, 125, 100, 100),
            (e) -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Adiós! :D")));
    /*
     * Gracias a la lambda, el "ActionListener" se queda en esa breve línea! Es MUY útil cuando quieres
     * hacer un botón que necesitas que llame a un determinado método de alguna clase :)
     */

    // Por último muestro el frame con... bueno, un revoltijo de botones :P
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Ahora, en el mismo paquete añade la clase `StaticWindowComponents`, el nombre del archivo debe ser igual que el de la clase :)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

/**
 * -test-
 *
 * @author Benito-B - 10/02/2021
 */
public class StaticWindowComponents {

    /**
     * Este método siempre devolverá un botón que permitirá salir de la aplicación
     * @param text Texto del botón
     * @param rectangle Posición y tamaño del botón
     * @return JButton con actionListener que termina la aplicación
     */
    public static JButton getExitButton(String text, Rectangle rectangle){
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.setBounds(rectangle);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        return button;
    }

    /**
     * Este método es similar al anterior, pero ... nos permite pasarle el listener! Es decir,
     * la acción de este botón dependerá de lo que le pasemos al momento de llamar al método!
     * @param text
     * @param rectangle
     * @param listener
     * @return
     */
    public static JButton getCustomButton(String text, Rectangle rectangle, ActionListener listener){
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.setBounds(rectangle);
        // Simplemente le añado el lístener que recibe el método!
        button.addActionListener(listener);
        return button;
    }

}
```

Como verás, tener métodos que devuelven objetos *prefabricados* es muy útil puesto que nos permite añadir múltiples objetos *iguales o similares* de manera muy rápida y sin repetirnos!

Además, el uso de lambdas y el paso de los *listener* como parámetro a dichos métodos nos abre un enorme abanico de posibilidades a la hora de crear múltiples instancias de elementos similares con funcionalidades ***MUY* diferentes**.

---

Espero que esto te sirva de ayuda para crear tus propios métodos y seguir aprendiendo. En el ejemplo tan solo he usado `JButton`s, pero esta técnica funcionará con cualquier otro objeto! *The sky is the limit*, así que ánimo, a practicar y a aprender! Para cualquier duda, aquí estamos.

---

Por cierto, con ese código se obtiene el siguiente monstruo... perdón, ventana:
[image: Resultado de ejecutar el código]

Comment: Hola @Benito-B paso tarde a agradecerte tu información. Me ayudo mucho tu ayuda. Un abrazo!